# How to generate multiple a tags with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I would like to create multiple `a` tags to populate a `div`. Writing this in HTML would take a lot of rows and a JavaScript script would make things easier. Unfortunately, I'm still learning it and I'm looking for some help.

Below is my HTML code that I want generated using JavaScript, inside `div id="countries"`

```
<div class="countries">
  <div id="Denmark">
    <h4>Denmark</h4>
<!-- number of links is variable to each country -->
    <a href="https://www.example.com">Link1</a>
    <a href="https://www.example2.com">Link2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some JS code

```
let countrySelect = document.getElementsByClassName('countries');

let links = ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com", "https://www.example3.com", "https://www.example4.com", "https://www.example5.com", "https://www.example6.com", "https://www.example7.com", "https://www.example7.com"];

// make an array of countries
let countries = ["Denmark", "Spain", "Italy", "Slovenia", "Malta", "Hungary", "Austria", "Czech Republic"];

// make a div
let makeDiv = document.createElement("div");
// add an ID to div just created
makeDiv.setAttribute('id', 'country');
// make an A tag
let tag = document.createElement("a");
tag.setAttribute('href', links[1]); // multiple links needed...integrate in a loop?

// make a loop to create multiple country divs
for (let index = 0; index < countries.length; index++) {
  // insert all the elements in the loop
}
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? Create the tag in the loop, append it to the div in question. If you're creating multiple elements with an ID please make sure each ID is unique. Unrelated, but it'd be cleaner to keep the country names and links in a *single* array of objects.

Comment: Can you use a server-side scripting language? (You need to check what options are available on your server.) Client-side JavaScript seems overkill for your purposes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `a` element and set its `href` and text in a loop.

```
countries.forEach(country => {
    let makeDiv = document.createElement("div");
    makeDiv.id = country;
    let h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    h4.innerText = country;
    makeDiv.appendChild(h4);

    links.forEach((link, i) => {
        let tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = link;
        tag.innerText = `Link${i+1}`;
        makeDiv.appendChild(tag);
    });

    countrySelect[0].appendChild(makeDiv);
});
```

Comment: I've added the loop for countries. In the question you said that the number of links varies by country, but you didn't show how to get each country's links, so my answer uses the same `links` array for all countries. Just add a way to get the country-specific value of `links` in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I pasted this code inside my fiddle and is giving me the following error: `countrySelect.appendChild is not a function` Why?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList, not a single node. Needed to index it.

Answer (score 0):

**a.** yes, create a loop. you can use also `countries.forEach(()=> ...)` btw.
**b.** dont forget to append the element before the loop continue.
**c.** a little suggestion - if the code is getting bigger, divide your code to little funtions with meaningful name.

good luck!